# выполнение кода через определенное время js

Tags: javascript

Привет
мне нужно выполнять определенную функцию раз в 0.5 секунды, но при этом не использовать setTimeout/setInterval. 
Подскажите, как это сделать с помощью Date.now()

на js,
спасибо заранее

Comment: домашнее задание?

Comment: то, для чего мне нужен этот код - это только мое дело. За грубость не сочтите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var interval = 500; //полсекунды
var startDate = Date.now();
while (true) {
  var nowDate = Date.now();
  if (nowDate-startDate >= interval) {
    startDate = nowDate;
    callSomeFunc();
  }
}
```

Comment: Если бы я использовал такой код в реальном проекте - мне б точно прилетело за это.

Comment: а в чем проблема?

Comment: while(true) - прямой способ повесить работу вкладки.

Comment: а если условие выхода из цикла прописать, тогда этот код не будет таким жутким?

Comment: Пока крутится while(true) - загрузка ЦП - 100%. Выход из цикла конечно исправит ситуацию, но всё равно.